# How to make an Excel file an interactive webpage?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

How can I make my Excel file work as a web page where people can enter data and it will stay there?  I am new to this!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Required technologies for this exercise: JavaScript, JQuery, PHP, AJAX and MySQL.  And Excel!  All this requires a minor edit, only adding 3 lines of text to the generated html page.

A running demonstration is at https://ip.jawfin.net

I'd like to state that the html of Excel Save As has been badly maligned - Excel 2013 generates a very clean html, its styles are built into the comments (so only 1 file is produced, no CSS), it's well indented and easy to read.  The only down-side is the names of classes of the styles are rather arbitrary!  No JavaScript, just plain html - it's a nice place to start then refine in Notepad++ or your favourite editor.  Mind you, the lack of CSS may come back to bite you, for extensive use I would recommend extracting the comments to build a CSS from.

Firstly, our Excel.  Here's one I made, and this is for a simple application which puts your IP in the cell you select on the screen.  (My practical use of this method was for a month scheduler, this "pick a colour" is good to demonstrate all the features and I hope will be easily adaptable.)  One change though, I scramble the visitor's IP as a protection.

Here's my Excel file: https://ip.jawfin.net/ip.xlsx

We don't export the whole spreadsheet, just select the cells you want which will make up the webpage.  In my case: -

[image: Excel Selected Cells]

With the cells selected, go into File / Save As, pick your folder, Save as Web Page (*.htm), choose only the Selection, give it a Title if desired, name it index.htm and Save!!

[image: Excel Save As HTML]

Now, rename index.htm to index.php as we will putting php code in it.  Now for the 3 lines of code to make this an interactive webpage.  Between the `</body>` and `</html>` at the bottom insert these 3 lines: -

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php include 'excel.php';?>
<script src="excel.js"></script>
```

so we have: -

```
</body>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php include 'excel.php';?>
<script src="excel.js"></script>

</html>
```

The *1st* line importing JQuery for our AJAX to work.

The *2nd* is to get the user's IP.  Note, this can do a lot more if required, for instance in my implementation I use it to log into a phpBB forum and get the logged-in username and permissions.  This php also shows how we can pass server php variables to the local javascript.

The *3rd* line is the brains, doing all the work and communicating with the server for updating and fetching data.

(You know, this really could just be one line of code if I embedded the script lines as echo's in the php - but that loses readability in my opinion.)

For the database: on your webserver log into your panel and create a new database for this app.
Then log into your phpMyAdmin to create the table[s] your application needs.
In this case it's one table, called cell_ip.  Its structure: -

```
field:cell; type:integer; index:primary + unique 
field:ip; type:text
```

Or as it appears in phpMyAdmin: -

[image: MySQL Table]

The files this project uses are: -

> **index.php** the one we just created in Excel, goes in the web folder
>
> **excel.php** the file which fetches server-side variables (note we could also use this to inject dynamically created controls)
>
> **excel.js** the script running local interface, also communicates with the server
>
> **server.php** the database handler on the server, deals with the AJAX requests and database manipulations
>
> **settings.php** just a means of storing the database configuration in a safe place

All these files go into the root of the web folder, ***except*** settings.php which goes in home, the folder above web, where the Internet cannot see it, but our server.php can.

Note the 4 php files are all doing completely different jobs:
   *index.php* is the web page they see, the only user visible php file.
   *excel.php* injects code into index.php, into the webpage, where it can get server-side settings for the client.
   *server.php* is like a program running on the server alone, an application which our webpage calls to save and load data into our server-side database.
   *settings.php* is just a glorified ini file, a quick means of storing sensitive info out of sight from the Internet.

All the source has relevant comments explaining the processes - but I'm willing to answer any questions I can, please note though that I am not an expert.  So, without further ado, the work source codes.

(Edit: As I can't fit the full source here I'll provide links. Please let me know if there is a smarter/preferred way.  As it is, I renamed these to .txt so it doesn't behave like a webpage!)

[index.php](https://ip.jawfin.net/index.php.txt)  - This too big to include, so download, or make it yourself from instructions above.

[excel.php](https://ip.jawfin.net/excel.php.txt)

```
<?php //excel.php
//Let's create a string specific to the user without giving away private info 
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //I'm going with hashing the md5 of their IP, then mod'ing back to 12 digits (from 38)
$hash = fmod(hexdec(md5($ip)),1e12);
echo '<script>'; //clever means of getting a php variable into javascript
echo 'var user_ip = ' . json_encode($hash) . ';'; //replace $hash with $ip you want to see the real address!
echo '</script>';
?>
```

[excel.js](https://ip.jawfin.net/excel.js.txt)

```
//excel.js
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); //needed to stop IE/Edge from caching AJAX GET requests

var cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td"); //array of all cells, excel assigns them type HTML table cell "td"
var updating = false; //prevent flicker if writing to the dataset and a read overwrites our status messages
var reentry = false; //prevent overlapping refresh. polls 1 a sec, 5 second time-out, could lead to massive overlap!
var addingStr = ' -- Adding IP --'; //const not used for backwards compatibility, IE9 etc.
var removeStr = ' -- Removing IP --';
var replaceStr = ' -- Replacing IP --';

for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) { //you can assign different aspects by the .innerHTML
        cells[i].style.cursor = 'cell'; //or 'pointer' - the default is the edit caret cursor which looks ugly
        cells[i].id = i; //tag our elements, but note this is happening AFTER the DCOM scan so getElementById() won't work
        cells[i].onclick = function() { cellClick(this); };
}
refreshScreen();
setInterval(function() { //ajax poll, refresh every second!
    refreshScreen();
}, 1000); 

function cellClick(cell) {
    updating = true; //don't allow the refresh to remove our status comment in the cell
    var mydata = 'action=';
    if (cell.innerHTML == "" || cell.innerHTML == "&nbsp;") {
    cell.innerHTML = addingStr;
      mydata += 'c'; //write into this cell the users IP
    } else {
        if (cell.innerHTML == user_ip) { //let's be smart and allow them to remove their own IP :)
            cell.innerHTML = removeStr;
            mydata += 'd'; //clear/delete this cell
        } else { //it's someone else, hijack them!!
            cell.innerHTML = replaceStr;
            mydata += 'u'; //update this cell
        }
    }
    mydata += '&cell=' + cell.id + '&ip=' + user_ip; //add our parameters
  $.ajax({ //JQuery ajax, so much cleaner and safer than using JavaScript ajax
        url: "server.php", //our server-side worker
        type: 'POST', //database changes, use POST, we don't want a webcrawler or a cache hitting a GET with parameters
        data: mydata,
        timeout: 5000, //5 second should be ample, but if they lose connectivity allow it to fail 
        success: 
          function(data) {
                updating = false;
                if (data != 1) { //no matter what, in this CRUD only 1 record should have been affected
                    alert('Data update error. Parameters: ' + data + '. Result: ' + data);
                }
                refreshScreen(); //refresh screen with new data
            },
        error: 
          function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { //put better error handling in if this fires too often!
//              alert('Data = ' + mydata + '. Error # = ' + xhr.status + '. Message = '+thrownError); //uncommend to debug
                updating = false;
                refreshScreen();
            }
    });
}

function refreshScreen() {
    if (updating) return; //just wait a second
    if (reentry) return; //we're already pending a refresh
    reentry = true;
    var mydata = 'action=r'; //we want to Read the data - stored in a varible in case we turn on our error alert
    $.ajax({
    url: "server.php",
      type: 'POST',
        data: mydata,
        timeout: 5000,
//      dataType: 'json', //just saves us a line of formatting text on success. !!commented out, not debug friendly
        success: function(data) {         //on recieve of reply
            reentry = false;
          if (updating) return; //they clicked between the request and the return here, just wait it out, next second!
            data = JSON.parse(data); //i prefer this instead of dataType:'json' so I check server script errors in the throw
            var results = []; //get our data into a 2 dimensional array (has 2 dimensions as our query returned 2 fields
            for(var x in data) { //get all the data ready before we touch the screen, cut down any possibly latency
                results.push(data[x]);
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) { //reset screen
                if (cells[i].innerHTML != removeStr) { //skipping the "Remove" messages (dirty read) - will clean up below if they were removed!
                    cells[i].innerHTML = ""; //clear field
                }
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { //now we stuff our cells with the IPs we have
                cells[results[i][0]].innerHTML = results[i][1]; //first array element is cell number, the second is the IP 
            }
            //as the "Remove" status was skipped above need to loop again to clear any found
            for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) { //backwards clean
                if (cells[i].innerHTML == removeStr) { //text is here as this cell didn't come through the SELECT
                    cells[i].innerHTML = ""; //clear field
                }
            }
        },
        error: 
          function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { //uncomment alert for debugging
            reentry = false;
//              alert('Query = ' + mydata + '. Error # = ' + xhr.status + '. Message = '+thrownError);
              //Note that xhr.status == 200 is an OK from the server but JSON invalid, so check for that first!
          }
    });
}
```

[server.php](https://ip.jawfin.net/server.php.txt)

```
<?php //server.php
if (!isset($_POST['action'])) exit; //no action parameter, just leave. could echo an error message if required though
$action = $_POST['action'];
if (!strpos(' crud',$action)) { //note the space out front, or else it'll fail on 'c' as it returns zero, which = false
    echo("Unknown action='$action'"); // took me ages to debug that, resulting in this line of code!!!!
    exit; //otherwise not one of ours, quit before SQL stuff starts
}   

require "../settings.php"; //lazy place to easily store settings out of reach from the Internet, parent of the web root. 
//Be aware I used ".." - if this server.php is not in the webroot then the database.php is not out of reach. 
//Note this method is easier than loading an .ini file and parsing it within an array.
if ($db_server == "") { //ASSERT: this should never fire as the require would fail on not find, but can't be too sure
    echo "Problem getting database settings.";
    exit;
}

$connection = mysql_connect($db_server, $db_username, $db_password); // Establishing Connection with Server
if (!$connection) {
    echo "Error connecting to database.";
    exit;
}
$db = mysql_select_db($db_database_ip, $connection); // Selecting Database
if (!$db) {
    echo "Specific database not found.";
    exit;
}

if ($action == 'c') { //note this will fail if there is a blank record against this cell, so check here
    $cell = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cell']); //extract our parameter
    $ip = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ip']);
    if ($ip == "") {
        echo "Cannot add blank IP in cell '$cell'";
    } else {
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO cell_ip(cell, ip) values ('$cell', '$ip')"); //Create Query
        echo $query; //always return the result, even if its unexpected. can hold error messages for debugging
    }
}

if ($action == 'r') { //JSON our database back to the client. 
//Note I am using the POST protol instead of GET, tidier on this server.php keeping all my server requests in one file
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT cell, ip FROM cell_ip"); //Read Query
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        $table_data[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($table_data); //return the whole dataset
}

if ($action == 'u') { //pinching someone else's cell with our ip, make sure the new ip exists too
    $cell = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cell']); 
    $ip = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ip']);     
    if ($ip == "") {
        echo "Cannot edit to a blank IP in cell '$cell'";
    } else {
        $query = mysql_query("UPDATE cell_ip SET ip = '$ip' WHERE cell = '$cell'"); //Update Query
        echo $query;
    }
}

if ($action == 'd') { //delete this cell
    $cell = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cell']); //extract our parameter
    $query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM cell_ip WHERE cell = '$cell'"); //Delete Query
    echo $query;
}

mysql_close($connection); //Note this was never opened if the caller failed the "action" validation, being polite to our sql
?>
```

[settings.php](https://ip.jawfin.net/settings.php.txt) (this goes in root home, change the values in this to suit)

```
<?php //settings.php
$db_server='localhost';
$db_username='root';
$db_password='root_password';
$db_database_ip='excel_ip';
?>
```

Things to note: -

If your database relies on the cell number they may change if you edit your Excel and republish the html.
This demo relies on the cell numbers only because it is only a demo - for instance you could put text in the cells and use that to identify your relevant cells.

If you run your server on CloudFlare and change any of your .js or .php they get cached, so you need to purge those files on the CloudFlare (Caching) after you upload them.

SECURITY!!! Your JavaScripts will be available to the end user, they cannot not be, as JS runs on the client - not matter how packaged or encrypted they can be discovered.  Do not have passwords or intellectual property in them.  This also means your AJAX requests can be launched maliciously, be sure to put extensive handling and filtering in your server-side php's.  I would also recommend employing a token + session handler to validate the calling client.

Final note: I wrote this for 2 reasons.  First I wanted to read this in 10 years time so I can see how hacky and newby I am now (this is my second day as a web developer), and secondly I do not wish anyone to go through the shameful and humiliating experience which I did when asking for help on this project on StackOverflow (you won't find my question about that though, it got deleted).  I hope this post is useful to somebody, I spent a whole day on designing it :)